# How To Duplicate Search Form Elements and Add Unique IDs

Tags: jquery, xml, ajax, forms, webforms

I'm working on building a search form [(here's the demo)](http://tomryandesign.com/dev/search-form-demo.html). Unfortunately, I've gotten to a point where I honestly have no idea how to do what I want to do next.

I need to add functionality that will cause the Add Another City button to duplicate the State/Province and City SELECTs, which are populated with XML data by an Ajax call, but with unique IDs so the form can ultimately combine the search terms with multiple cities to produce the results of the search. Also, it should be able to add no more than 4 additional cities.

Can anyone at least point me in the direction of how I should start with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding, you don't really need to generate IDs for each created element, you can simply have a class and access them with that.

I threw this together to illustrate the idea:

http://jsfiddle.net/2SLrF/

Everything works entirely off of class.

NOTE: I went a little crazy on the chaining because it was quick and dirty, you'd probably want to separate it out a bit for maintainability.

If for some other reason you do need to generate IDs, you can simply create a counter variable and just append that to the end of the ID so that it's unique.

EDIT: The same example, expanded and commented.  http://jsfiddle.net/2SLrF/1/

Comment: That's interesting. You're doing a couple things there that I wasn't familiar with (.clone() for example). But I'm having trouble merging that into my code. It clones the second SELECT with the same ID, so when you change the first state field, it changes the options on both city fields.

Comment: You're still using IDs.  The trick to what I posted is that it is not using IDs at all.  It is using the layout of the page and a class that is shared by all elements of a given type to access the elements.  For instance, `$(".s1").live("change", function() {
        $(this).next(".s2").show();
    });` is saying, when any element with a class of `s1` changes, find the next element which has a class of `s2`.  So it will always grab the `s2` directly after the `s1` which has changed.  This is why only one city select is affected.

Comment: @Tom see the update to my answer.  I took the example and expanded it out and added comments to explain it.  Hope that helps.

Comment: I've implemented your code and changed it slightly to work with my Ajax calls, but if you run it on the demo URL I posted above, you'll see that once you choose a state the first time, all subsequent city dropdowns will have that state's cities listed. In other words, choosing the state in the second, third, fourth, etc., set of dropdowns does not activate the correct city dropdown.

Comment: You're not using `this`.  Have a look at http://remysharp.com/2007/04/12/jquerys-this-demystified/ which explains `this`.  You need to use `this` to reference the element that was clicked rather than the first element.

Comment: I am using `this` in several places. Do you mean to say that I'm not using it properly or that I could be using it more?

Comment: In the part you're having an issue with it is not used at all.  Inside `$("select.state").live(` you are using `$("span.city")` and `$("select.state")`, this will return ALL spans with the given classes.  You need to use `this` in order to find the correct ones.  For instance, to get the correct `select.state` use `$(this)`.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I think I've got it. Any tips on how to restrict the `.clone` to 5 iterations?

Comment: You can use `$('select.state').length` to see how many there are and use that to either ignore the click when there are 5 or hide/disable the button once you've added 5.

Comment: Okay, that was easy enough. Thanks! :)